# How to display a div inwards to viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a div in which, I need to display the div as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can we acheive this using css or with any script. Need help

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the skew transformation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew

Comment: can you give a sample code of how to achieve this

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you supply some code we can help refine it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) and [`transform: rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=control).

If you take a look at this link, [*perspective*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective), you'll find some interesting things one can do

```css
div {
    margin-top: 40px;
    perspective: 100px;
}
img {
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotateY(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and will this work in IE9

Comment: @Ram No, from IE10. For IE9 you need to create this as an image. Also, if you have such requirements, you need to add that to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic idea.

```css
.parent {
  perspective: 600px;

}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Banners</div>
</div>
```